# Error mounting shared folder for KVM Solaris guest

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, mount, kvm

Followed [this](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/9p_virtio) guide on how to set up a shared folder between a KVM Host(Ubuntu 12.04) and Guest (Solaris 10 Sparc). On the last part of the it requires you to mount the shared folder and typed in this command.

```
mkdir /mnt/shared
mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio /hostshare /mnt/shared
```

But i got an error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /hostshare,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Any ideas on how to fixed this?